# Meteor mobile application - embedded database

Tags: javascript, android, database, mobile, meteor

I want to develop simple app for Android OS using Meteor JavaScript platform. Is there a way to embedd small database for such app. Or I must use data served by web applications API that I must develop also?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Meteor + Phonegap integration. Then you could use some little database like sqlite.